# docker stack deploy, restart_policy, delete exited containers

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-stack

How to get rid of containers in status 'Exited' in docker swarm?

docker stack deploy -c ./test.yml test

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  test-serv:
    image: redbom/test:latest
    user: "root"
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 1s
```

image:redbom/test:latest - is test image with bash sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'sllep 8'
sleep 8
exit 0
```

After 10 minutes: docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
b7d26ca8382c        redbom/test:latest   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   4 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                                    test_test-serv.1.5k0esbhtx0k6m7kmcuo5w3obs
0a7415032fa2        redbom/test:latest   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   14 seconds ago      Exited (0) 3 seconds ago                        test_test-serv.1.tq2fif5r0pny18ee248kisw6z
337cb3b7f1e1        redbom/test:latest   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   23 seconds ago      Exited (0) 13 seconds ago                       test_test-serv.1.hzdyhk9202le9oh9senuw38l3
21e06ac40795        redbom/test:latest   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   33 seconds ago      Exited (0) 23 seconds ago                       test_test-serv.1.i4poxgv4zfwrzl3ag25b5rco4
af85c618ba7d        redbom/test:latest   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   43 seconds ago      Exited (0) 33 seconds ago                       test_test-serv.1.b1jzxq2t2lb9e0tl5hqvzxr4t
```

How to configure test.yml, so that there are no containers in status Exited?
I want, that docker stack delete Exited containers after itself. I do not need them.

Answer (score 2):

What you see is the result of the task history retention limit, which defaults to 5. You can set the retention limit with `docker swarm update --task-history-limit ${int}` (make sure to replace ${int} with an integer). I found setting the value to 2 provides a good balance between cleaning up exited containers and still beeing able to rollback failed stack deployments.

Though, since you don't need the task history, set it to 0. This should cleanup all  exited containers (though, not sure if this applies to services deployed before the change).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. 
--task-history-limit 0